# How does OpenStack Glance work with Keystone and what exactly are these configuration options for?

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone, openstack-glance

I am configuring Glance to authenticate against Keystone.  It works
but I am unsure exactly how some of the authentication options
interact.

I started with the [configuring glance](http://glance.openstack.org/configuring.html) documentation, but this
doesn't actually document any of these options.  I found the
[authentication documentation](http://glance.openstack.org/authentication.html), which discusses
some of them, but does not actually document `auth_uri`.

The [example glance configuration](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/glance-registry-conf-file.html) in the [OpenStack
Install and Deploy Manual](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/) looks like this:

```
[filter:authtoken]
paste.filter_factory = keystone.middleware.auth_token:filter_factory
service_protocol = http
service_host = 127.0.0.1
service_port = 5000
auth_host = 127.0.0.1
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
auth_uri = http://127.0.0.1:5000/
admin_token = 012345SECRET99TOKEN012345
```

The [authentication documentation](http://glance.openstack.org/authentication.html) says:

> Those variables beginning with auth_ point to the Keystone Admin
>   service. This information is used by the middleware to actually
>   query Keystone about the validity of the authentication tokens.

Okay.  So how does `auth_uri` interact with `auth_host`, `auth_port`,
and `auth_protocol`?  Can one simply provide `auth_uri` and discard
the other options?  Is there a corresponding `service_uri`
configuration option?  And why does the port in `auth_uri` correspond to the `service_port` in the above configuration instead of the `auth_port`?

Keystone refers to port `35357` as the "admin" port, which to me
suggests that this would only be required for administration of
keystone (creating/deleting services, tenants, etc).  Glance instead
refers to this as the "auth" port, which suggests a different use.
What exactly is provided by the service on port 35357 that is not
provided by the service on port 5000?

Answer (score 2):

First check out:  http://docs.openstack.org/ops/OpenStackOperationsGuide.pdf

Looking at the glance source code...

```
tools/migrate_image_owners.py
```

... is the only file that references auth_uri.

> It appears this variable is all over the place and it assists with
>   auth token handling in clients and across the whole of openstack. 
>   It's not used by glance specifically... but it is used by utilities
>   that work with the middleware stack.

As for the differences between 5000 and 35357 on keystone...

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html  has a pretty explicit discussion of what API examples work on both, or not.

My understanding of port 5000 is that its specific purpose is to allow for public API authentication to keystone, so you don't need to expose 35357 just to allow people to authenticate to it.

As for why there are auth creds inside of each of the openstack components that tie into keystone... truthfully I don't. know.

However I should point out that API v2 is coming in grizzly.  Not fully documented yet, and it will begin to introduce some radical changes in how keystone operates.